# CSS Floating Right and Left

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get 2 divs to line up side by side in a parent div then repeat the same on the next row however. When I float the 2 child divs in the second row everything ends up  trying to go to the top.

Div Code

```
<div class="location_row">
<div class="loc_title_div loc_title">

</div>
<div>
    <div class="addr_div addr_text">

    </div>
    <div class="loc_img_div">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="location_row">
<div class="loc_title_div loc_title">
</div>
<div>
    <div class="addr_div addr_text" >
       </div>
    <div class="loc_img_div">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.loc_title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.addr_text {
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #000;
}

.loc_img {
    border: 3px;
    border-color: #1e398d;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.loc_title_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #1e398d;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.addr_div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.loc_img_div {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.location_row {
}
```

Comment: Half of those elements don't even have heights.. you might want to check that out,

Comment: Sigh...must just have needed a fresh set of eyes adding a height to .location_row took care of it. I thought they should still stack as before.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use property `clear` to clean up the floated elements of the previous row : Try this --

```
.location_row{
  clear:both;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/ukdwE/3/**

On this link you can check [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) with more options to `clear` your floats.

Answer (score 0):

I think specifying the top attribute for the inner divs will solve your problem.

```
.addr_div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    top:xx% or xpx;
}

.loc_img_div {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    top:xx% or xpx;
}
```

Need to specify top for the divs in both rows to line up correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
.location_row{
    width:45%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LbTLr/`" title="JS Fiddle Url">Check the url this may solve your problem